# Retrieving values if keys of the dictionary are in frozensets

Tags: python, dictionary, set, key, frozenset

I'm using frozensets to keep the keys of my dictionary to take an advantage of union, difference and intersection operations. But when I'm trying to retrieve values by keys from the dictionary through dict.get() it yields a None value.

```
newDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': True}
stKeys = set(newDict)
stA = frozenset('a')
stB = frozenset('b')
stC = frozenset('c')
stD = frozenset('d')

print(stKeys)
print(newDict.get(stA & stKeys))
print(newDict.get(stB & stKeys))
print(newDict.get(stC & stKeys))
print(newDict.get(stD & stKeys))
```

*Produce:*

```
>>>None
>>>None
>>>None
>>>None
```

And even:

```
print(newDict.get(stA))
print(newDict.get(stB))
print(newDict.get(stC))
print(newDict.get(stD))
```

*Produce:*

```
>>>None
>>>None
>>>None
>>>None
```

**How to retrieve values from the dictionary if your keys are in frozensets?**

> Thanks to *Martijn Pieters*! The answer is DVO (Dictionary view
>   objects) and the generator expression if you want to add the result to
>   a list()

Comment: Why do you think the keys are frozen sets?

Comment: Python dictionaries do not support lookups by set like that, no.

Comment: What output were you expecting instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) if you want to look for *set intersections*:

```
for key in newDict.viewkeys() & stA:
    # all keys that are in the intersection of stA and the dictionary
```

In Python 3, returning dictionary views is the default; you can use `newDict.keys()` here:

```
for key in newDict.keys() & stA:
    # all keys that are in the intersection of stA and the dictionary
```

Demo on Python 3:

```
>>> newDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': True}
>>> stA = frozenset('a')
>>> stB = frozenset('b')
>>> stC = frozenset('c')
>>> stD = frozenset('d')
>>> newDict.keys() & stA
{'a'}
>>> for key in newDict.keys() & stA:
...     print(newDict[key])
... 
1
```

Comment: yes, DVO (dictionary view objects) do the magic, but the result of the intersection is a new set again :( So I can't append this result to my list: `aList.append(newDict.viewkeys() & stA)`

Comment: @Michael: you can *extend* your list: `aList.extend(newDict.viewkeys() & stA)`. Set intersections always produce 0 or more elements, not just 1.

Comment: yes but it will be a dictionary key not the dictionary value! My question marked out by the bold font was: **How to retrieve values from the dictionary....?** To be more clear you can't write `aList.append(newDict.get(newDict.viewkeys() &stA))` and `aList.extend(newDict.get(newDict.viewkeys() &stA))` is also impossible :( It is all I want.

Comment: `aList.append(newDict[newDict.viewkeys() & stA])` retrieving value by the key from the dictionary instead of dict.get() method doesn't work too (

Comment: You'd use a generator expression: `aList.extend(newDict[k] for k in newDict.viewkeys() & setA)`.

Comment: yeeeew! Oh my god! Man you've saved the world and made my day.. It would take me a week If I had been trying to solve this issue alone. **Thanks a million!**

Answer (score 1):

To create frozen set keys you need to actually create frozen sets and use them as keys:

```
newDict = {
    frozenset('a'): 1,
    frozenset('b'): 2,
    frozenset('c'): 3,
    frozenset('d'): True
}
```

Test:

```
>>> {frozenset('a'):1}[frozenset('a')]
1
```

Comment: My example above is simplified version (prototype) of the real code. In my case I do not create the dictionary, I'm receiving it from the function argument (command line): `def foo(var, **kwDict)`. So I can't use your advice but anyway thanks too.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can do what you are trying to do, at least in 3.6.1 and I suspect 2.7.x as well:

```
newDict = {frozenset('a'): 1, frozenset('b'): 2, frozenset('c'): 3, 'd': True}
stKeys = set(newDict)
stA = frozenset('a')
print(stA)
stB = frozenset('b')
stC = frozenset('c')
stD = 'd'

print(newDict[stA])
print(newDict[stB])
print(newDict[stC])
print(newDict[stD])
```

Output:

```
frozenset({'a'})
1
2
3
True
```

The problem seems to be that the key was being assigned as a string object and not a frozenset, yet the search was set to look for a frozenset.